# how can i give addtab function in second column easyui datagrid

Tags: datagrid, tabs, jquery-easyui

i want **addtab** in datagrid. when click the on the data i want addtab. how can i call the **onClick** function in second column of every row.

```
<th field="name" width="50" editor="{type:'validatebox',options:{required:true}}" sortable="true" onClick="addtab2('$('#name').val()','nameview.php')">Tariff Name</th>
```

i given like this but it's not coming. is der any way

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use formatter,

Please refer below link,

http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=DataGrid&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=